# Any open source editor to make video games online without programming knowledge?

Tags: html5, server, browser-based-games, open-source, editors

With [Scratch](http://scratch.mit.edu/) we can create video games online, from its web platform, and publish them on the same web. I could download its [source code](http://wiki.scratch.mit.edu/wiki/Scratch_Source_Code) and use it, as many others already did (see [Scratch modifications](http://wiki.scratch.mit.edu/wiki/Scratch_Modification)). **Unfortunately, we need programming knowledge to use it**. Actually, Scratch is mainly for teaching kids to code.

I also found editors like [Construct 2](https://www.scirra.com/), [GameSalad Creator](http://gamesalad.com/creator) and many others (just type on Google: [create a video game without programming](http://www.google.es/search?q=create%20a%20video%20game%20without%20programming)). With those editors we can create video games without coding. **Unfortunately they are neither open source nor web platform. They need to be installed on Windows or Mac.**

Do you know some editor like [Construct 2](https://www.scirra.com/) or [GameSalad Creator](http://gamesalad.com/creator) but open source and executable from a web server? Maybe some HTML5 game engine can do it?

Comment: If you're asking about the Scratch "code" editor, there's a name for it. I believe it may be open-source, as it's used in multiple game makers (eg. Stencyl)

Comment: @ashes999, Stencyl seems easier to use than Scratch, so maybe it could be OK. Unfortunately, it does not seem installable and executable from a server.

Comment: You could ask such a question on [softwarerecs.se] (I created a similar one, but for installation on a GNU/Linux desktop: [Creating a browser game (2D top-down perspective) without programming skills](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/10547/60))

Comment: OK @unor. I have requested to migrate it to the site you suggest. Thanks!

Comment: Typically, we don't migrate questions to sites that are still in beta. I suggest re-posting the question there instead of having it migrated.

Comment: Further, answers don't go in the question. Please don't edit them in include answers.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is not any other way to answer the question, as it has been market as off topic @Byte56 (wrongly I believe because there is nothing to discuss)

Comment: Now nobody will be able to read the answer as you removed it @Byte56, that's the only truth.

Comment: Yes, we don't abuse the question and answer system to post answers in questions. Off topic questions aren't allowed to break those rules either. The question is off topic because it doesn't have a correct answer, it just generates a list of responses, with no answer being more correct than the next. As I said, you can post the question again yourself on the other stack exchange.

Comment: @Byte56, I challenge you find ONE solution of that list of solutions. Actually, a list must have more than one solution, but I bet you can't find one ;)